# "Dynamic" port forwarding?

Tags: networking

I'm developing a server that will be hosted on a Raspberry Pi in C# for a customer. One of the biggest issues is they want a local server, but one they could plug in anywhere and have it work.

My brain went to no-ip first but they aren't willing to pay to have a permanent IP, so I found dynu (basically a free version). So having a permanent IP is no problem, just I have to find a way to port forward on the fly... how would that be possible?

Comment: Port forwarding happens on the network device that is performing NAT. That is usually a router or firewall between the server and the public Internet. In addition, a firewall may simply be blocking all incoming connections. Trying to implement a solution on the server will not address the actual problem.

Comment: It doesn't have to be port forwarding just a way in which clients can connect to the server no matter on what network it gets plug in

Comment: The way things like IoT devices do this is to connect to a cloud on the public Internet. Basically, you have a server on the public Internet where the end device connects to open a connection into whichever network it is. Users outside that network connect to the public server, which then facilitates a connection to the remote server. This will cost money because you need a permanent, publicly hosted server.

Comment: Alright, could that be done through a website?

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer that. Think about how you can have a camera (or thermostat, lighting control, or whatever) in your home behind a NAT and firewall, and control it from your mobile phone from anywhere. The home device contacts a cloud server at the vendor to open a connection in the NAT and/or firewall. You mobile phone application then connects to the vendor's cloud server too, which facilitates a connection from the mobile phone over the connection that the home device created. That is how it is done, but it isn't inexpensive.

Comment: Is it possible to host it via a VPN?

Comment: That is basically what I explained. You are going to need an external device on the public Internet that acts as an intermediary, and that can be a VPN service. For a device like your server that sits behind a NAT or firewall, it must originate a connection to the public Internet in order to be able to receive traffic. Traffic originating from the Internet to  your device would be blocked, unless it can use an existing connection that was originated from your device.

Comment: Of course, it may end up on a network that blocks any such attempt. For example, trying to do something like that on my company's network would end in failure because there are measures in place to block such attempts.  It is really bypassing the network security, and it can lead to exploits. That is what happened to Target that cost them any millions of dollars, which is why such things are often blocked; it is a security hole.